# Is there any way to parallelize with plumber in windows?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, future, plumber

I want to parallelize a task with plumber, handling multiple requests at the same time. I have found an example that I have put in practice in windows and it doesn't work, but taking the same example to linux it does get the parallel calculation.
Is there any way to get the parallelization in windows using the future library? or using doParallel + foreach

The example i used:
[text](https://community.rstudio.com/t/future-with-plumber/94477)

```
# ./plumber.R
library(future)
library(promises)
# fix the number of workers to 5
future::plan(future::multisession(workers = 5))

#' @param msg The message to echo back.
#' @serializer text
#' @get /echo
function(msg = ""){
  future({
    Sys.sleep(5)
    paste0(Sys.getpid(), " - ", as.character(Sys.time()), "\n")
  })}
```

```
library(plumber)
pr("plumber.R") %>% pr_run(port = 8080)
```

When I run this code in windows and send multiple requests to it, the process runs serially, as if the future package does not work.

How I tested:

```
library(httr)
responses <- lapply(1:6, function(i) {
  GET("http://127.0.0.1:8080/echo")
})

print(responses)
```

And the results:

```
[[1]]
Response [http://127.0.0.1:8080/echo]
  Date: 2024-01-23 08:37
  Status: 200
  Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
  Size: 34 B
31320 - 2024-01-23 09:37:27.24171

[[2]]
Response [http://127.0.0.1:8080/echo]
  Date: 2024-01-23 08:37
  Status: 200
  Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
  Size: 35 B
31320 - 2024-01-23 09:37:32.457364

[[3]]
Response [http://127.0.0.1:8080/echo]
  Date: 2024-01-23 08:37
  Status: 200
  Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
  Size: 35 B
31320 - 2024-01-23 09:37:37.667452

[[4]]
Response [http://127.0.0.1:8080/echo]
  Date: 2024-01-23 08:37
  Status: 200
  Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
  Size: 35 B
31320 - 2024-01-23 09:37:42.834899

[[5]]
Response [http://127.0.0.1:8080/echo]
  Date: 2024-01-23 08:37
  Status: 200
  Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
  Size: 35 B
31320 - 2024-01-23 09:37:47.994111

[[6]]
Response [http://127.0.0.1:8080/echo]
  Date: 2024-01-23 08:37
  Status: 200
  Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
  Size: 35 B
31320 - 2024-01-23 09:37:53.170176
```

I got the same pid as you can see.

I would like to know if it is possible to run this on windows.

Thank you

Comment: As far as I know, each request to `plumber` will be in a separate session, so it can already handle multiple requests at a time.

Comment: @mhovd what do you mean? `plumber` without `future` runs one session, one process, and it blocks other requests when busy.

Comment: I think you're missing a close brace `}` on your function, though I'm guessing that's not a problem in your real code

Comment: How are you testing your multiple requests? How do you know they're being run serially?

Comment: I just tested on win11 with multiple tabs, they have different PIDs printed, and repeated queries repeat the same set of PIDs. Please [edit] your question to explain why you think it is being run serially in one process.

Comment: @r2evans i just included the test process and i tested in win 10 and 11

Comment: Your test client is linear, consecutive. It did not mean that the server is not parallel.